# Complex Numbers and Euler/Polar Form

Tags: complex-numbers

Say you have a complex number with $|z|=2$ and argument of $-\pi/3$.

Why is it not valid to say $e^{-\pi/3i} = e^{5\pi/3i}$?

Is it still valid to say $2cis(-\pi/3) = 2cis(5\pi/3)$?

Comment: They look valid to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be careful with your expressions. It *is* valid to say that $e^{-(\pi/3)i} = e^{(5\pi/3)i}$ because 
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
e^{-(\pi/3)i} & = \cos(-\pi/3) + i\sin(-\pi/3)\\
&= \cos(2\pi - (\pi/3)) + i\sin(2\pi - (\pi/3))\\
& = \cos(5\pi/3) + i\sin(5\pi/3)\\
& = e^{(5\pi/3)i}
\end{array}
$$
So, similarly, $2\mbox{cis}(-\pi/3) = 2\mbox{cis}(5\pi/3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$

So, $e^{-\frac{\pi}{3}i}=\cos(-\frac{\pi}{3})+i\sin(-\frac{\pi}{3})=\cos(\frac{5\pi}{3})+i\sin(\frac{5\pi}{3})=e^{\frac{5\pi}{3}i}$

Thus, they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

It is valid:

$$e^{-\frac{\pi i}{3}} = e^{-\frac{\pi i}{3}} \cdot 1 = e^{-\frac{\pi i}{3}} e^{2 \pi i} = e^{-\frac{\pi i}{3} + 2 \pi i} = e^{\frac{5 \pi i}{3}}.$$